# vue-moment issue in laravel-inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, momentjs, inertiajs

I tried importing vue-moment and initializing it by using .use(VueMoment) as shown below. But after i do that the whole app shows error. Anyone facing the same problem?

```
    require('./bootstrap');

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { App as InertiaApp, plugin as InertiaPlugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment' ////////imported vue-moment

const el = document.getElementById('app');

createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({
        methods: {
            route,
            validationError(field){
                if(this.$page.props.errors && this.$page.props.errors[field]){
                    return this.$page.props.errors[field];
                }
                else{
                    return null;
                }
            }
    } })
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
    .use(VueMoment) /////use vue-moment
    .mount(el);

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

[This is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk7vY.png)

Answer (score 1):

first install moment by

```
npm install moment

<template>
{{today}}
</template>
<script>
import   moment from 'moment'
export default {
 name:'Home',
 data(){
  return{
  today:moment().startOf('day').toDate(), moment().endOf('day').toDate() 
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: With this I then need to import it everywhere i use moment right. I am trying to make it available globally and it didn't work in the latest laravel-inertia with vue3

Answer (score 0):

there is a working example of how to import 'vue-moment' from my Laravel + inertia project

```
const vm = new Vue({
  metaInfo: {
    titleTemplate: title => (title ? `${title} - Ping CRM` : 'Ping CRM'),
  },
  store,
  render: h =>
    h(App, {
      props: {
        initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
        resolveComponent: name => import(`@/Pages/${name}`).then(module => module.default),
      },
    }),
}).$mount(el)

Vue.use(require('vue-moment'))
```

Comment: okay, the latest laravel-inertia is using vue3 and I am facing this error there. This code you sent works. Of course i can import moment everytime i use it. Just trying to figure out what went wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Might help someone who is using InertiaJs with Vue and want to declare globally.

In app.js

```
createInertiaApp({
id: 'app',
setup({ el, App, props}) {
    let app = createApp({
        render: () => {
            return h(App, props);
        },
    });

    //you can declare any other variable you want like this
    app.config.globalProperties.$moment = moment;
    app.use(
        store,
        .....
    ).mount(el);
},
});
```

Now in the vue file you can call moment by

```
this.$moment(this.time,'H:m').format('hh:mm a');
```